# With the kernel compiled by myself, when install VMware modules, it prompts Kernel headers not found

Tags: linux, kernel, vmware-workstation

With the kernel compiled by myself, when install VMware modules, it prompts Kernel headers not found.

My kernel source code is here:

> /root/kernel/linux-3.7

Where is the kernel headers?

Answer (score 1):

They should be installed in `/usr/include/linux`, probably also in `/usr/include/asm-generic` and possibly other subdirectories in the include directory (`video` comes to mind).

Comment: I found the solution: ln -s /root/kernel/linux-3.7/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /root/kernel/linux-3.7/include/linux/version.h

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
ln -s /root/kernel/linux-3.7/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /root/kernel/linux-3.7/include/linux/version.h
```